# Reopening popular question about voice control

Tags: discussion

Over six years ago I asked a [question about existing voice control solutions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/2988/4310), which was closed a few days later as opinion-based. At the time I didn't care about it very much, since by then I had already selected a solution for my problem. However, I notice it remains the top result when searching for "voice control", so it may be beneficial to reopen it.

What would it take to fix this question? I would say it is already objective enough — it specifies a concrete problem (voice recognition), target platform (Linux) and a prioritized requirement list (ability to recognize Brazilian Portuguese, failing that English in a foreign accent, and preferably a self-contained local module over cloud-based) — but obviously I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. Shopping questions which ask for a list of options are also effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) and answers to this kind of question lose value over time as the options change. Old projects fall into disuse, new projects are created, requirements and best practice change.

As we are looking to build a corpus of knowledge, answers which explain how to solve a problem without reference to specific products or projects are far more likely to be valuable 5 years down the line, than time limited recomendations. For instance, 3 links in answers to your original question are now broken and without additional context those answers are devalued.

Since we prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, in general it is better ask *How do I solve this problem?* than *What's available to solve my problem in this way?* as you may preclude answers providing better solutions.

If you write a new question, ideally referencing your original, describing the problems you've had since, what you tried and what you've considered and hopefully it will be embraced by the community.

Note that while a search for "Voice Control" may be high on search listings for you, that's probably because you have visited it numerous times before, for me, the question isn't listed in the first few pages of search results.

Comment: I don't see how the question "how to provide voice control on a Linux robot" is anymore opinion-based than any other "how to..." question (unless you're suggesting Linux may be gone at any moment). It also hardly matches the "shopping question" definition on the link you provided.

Comment: I also made the point of searching "voice control" from a different computer where I never logged in to the site, and still got that post as top result. Maybe the reason you're not getting it is some quirk of geo-targetting?

Comment: The solutions presented for the question — creating a local client for the Google Speech API, training a custom corpus for Julius — remain valid six years on, as do most of the links shared.

Comment: Of the 3 broken links, two could easily be fixed (which I just did, thanks for pointing that out) and the only one that couldn't be recovered, [robotergarten](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/4461/robotergarten)'s homepage, did have enough accompanying context that we could reconstruct the information there if we needed.

Comment: That the question and answers remain relevant to this day is likely the reason why it is the second most viewed in the [speech-processing](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech-processing) tag, only surpassed by [Best microphone for speech recognition tasks](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/3207/4310) — which would probably be more of a "shopping question", ironically.

Comment: @xperroni - I came across this post because I was looking for Mark's meta topic on closing off-topic questions, because I'm voting to close quite a few "how to" questions. Any "how do I...?" question is an unbounded design question. You could do it in any number of ways, and all are equally valid. There's no "right answer" to give, so there's also no "right answer" to choose. IMO, any how-to question here should be closed. There are sites like Instructables for how-to guides.

Comment: @xperroni - My thumbrule when trying to decide if a question is on-topic or not, personally speaking, is, "Is there knowledge to impart?" If you could ask the question in such a way that someone could *teach* an answer, instead of linking a set of libraries for example, then I'd be all for it. I think that it would go from "How do I do voice control on Linux," to something like, "How does voice control work?" Another way to consider the criteria would be, "Is this a good prompt for a Wikipedia article?" Again, knowledge to impart and a correct answer to select.